# Hypothetical: Suing over destroyed property given away freely?

Tags: property

Scenario: Person A gives person B an item, for free, with known (either explicit or implicit) intended use. Person B takes the item, with the objective of using the item in a way, contrary to the use intended by A. There is no specific law governing the use of the item (i.e. no copyright protection, etc).

Is person B in violation of a contract, or is the item now B's to do with as he pleases, including destroying it? And what are the potential consequences?

Answer (score 2):

There is no contract here as there is not consideration on both sides (B did not give A anything for the item). As such, A has gifted the item to B: B owns it and can do whatever they like with it, including destroying it. Neither party has any liability to the other.

Comment: So then you're ignoring the concept of conditional gifts? What about engagement rings? What about contributions to charity?

Comment: What about them? They don't appear in your OP and I try to answer the question asked - I can't answer the ones you are thinking of but don't post. I take "given away freely" to mean, you know: given away freely, that is, without obligation or condition.

Comment: Sorry. "Freely" as in "with no cost or expectation of returns." But within the question itself, I state that it is given "with known (either explicit or implicit) intended use."

Comment: A car has a known and expected use - to be driven. However, if I own it I can use it for other purposes like selling it or setting it on fire (subject to other law) without a previous owner having a say. Perhaps you should post a different question asking what you really want to know?

Comment: The question is fine. If I give a gift, with stipulations, either explicit or implicit, of how the thing is to be used, there is legal precedent which allows me to revoke the gift if it is misused.

Comment: I disagree that the question, as posed, corresponds with the question you are describing in the comments. I am happy with my answer to the question as posed. I invite you to separately ask the question described - there is no need to be parsimonious with questions.

Comment: @vasshu: The situations you refer to in these comments cover cases when there was a contract. I can pay you $X do do Y, but then the money isn't a gift. I can give you object Z to do Y, but it still isn't a gift.

Comment: Then technically conditional gifts are not gifts at all. That's fine, but it is what they are called. Example: I'll give you $1,000 for college.

Comment: They are called contracts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, was the item given in the expectation that B would give it back?  I don't really know the law in this case, but I imagine there's something there in that A expected B to be able to return the property in a state similar to the state under which it was lent out.

If A really did *give* the item to B (no expectation that it would be returned), then they don't expect it back, so the question is moot.